# Backup files to Windows share from Mac 10.3.9 schell script throws permission denied errors

Tags: mac, shell, shell-script, smbfs

So I have this script I'm working on to try and copy a couple files to a windows server as a backup. It appears as though I am able to mount the share well enough, however I seem to be unable to copy the files to the share.

This is the script:

`#!/bin/sh
mkdir /Volumes/BACKUP
mount_smbfs -f 777 -d 777 "//domain;domain\user:pass@server/backup" /Volumes/BACKUP
cp /Library/Application\ Support/path/to/file1 /Volumes/BACKUP
cp /Library/Application\ Support/path/to/file2 /Volumes/BACKUP
umount /Volumes/BACKUP 
rm -r /Volumes/BACKUP`

This is what the terminal tells me:

`computer:~/Desktop myuser$ ./Backup.sh
mount_smbfs: No credentials cache found krb5_cc_get_principal
cp: /Volumes/BACKUP/file1: Permission denied
cp: /Volumes/BACKUP/file2: Permission denied
computer:~/Desktop myuser$`

I know there's a piece that I'm missing, I'm just not entirely to sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. Apparently using the username style of "DOMAIN\username" allows the share to be mounted, but not written to. I changed the script to account for this and it results in the following (simplified for more general use):

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /Volumes/BACKUP
mount_smbfs "//domain;user:pass@server/backup" /Volumes/BACKUP
cp /path/to/file1 /Volumes/BACKUP
cp /path/to/file2 /Volumes/BACKUP
umount /Volumes/BACKUP 
rm -r /Volumes/BACKUP
```

Hopefully this helps those that come after. ;D